# Cannot convert argument 1 from '*' to "std::string'

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have an error, that is filling up my logs with 8 errors. The error reads Error    1   error C2664: 'Node::Node(const Node &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'CarPart *' to 'std::string' I am not sure how to diagnose or fix this problem. Thanks ahead for the help. There is a lot of code for this project so I am just going to post what I have and let you folks read through it, let me know if I can sum it up a little easier. The error occurs in the driver when the new CarPart is invoked. Also I know that the printList function is incomplete in the driver and that is my next question, I am not sure how to get it to print the list with the information that I have fill out for my header and implementation. The driver was provided by the study text, I just need it to compile and execute.

Header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>

class CarPart
{

private:
    // Variable Name: partNumber
    // Purpose: Variable that contains a unique identifier
    // Parameters: None
    // Returns: None
    // Pre-conditions: Must be of type string
    // Post-conditions: None
    std::string partNumber;

    // Variable Name: partDescription
    // Purpose: Variable that contains the parts description
    // Parameters: None
    // Returns: None
    // Pre-conditions: Must be of type string
    // Post-conditions: None
    std::string partDescription;

    // Variable Name: price
    // Purpose: Variable that contains price
    // Parameters: None
    // Returns: None
    // Pre-conditions: Must be of type double
    // Post-conditions: None
    double price;

public:
    // Default Constructor Name: CarPart
    // Purpose: Default constructor to initialize
    // Parameters: None
    // Returns: None
     CarPart();

     // Parameterized Constructor Name: CarPart
     // Purpose: Parameterized constructor to initialize data types
     // Parameters: A string value, a string value, and a double value
     // Returns: None
     CarPart(std::string partNum, std::string partDesc, double partPrice);

     // Function Name: getPartNumber
     // Purpose: To get the number for the part
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     // Pre-conditions: Part number cannot be NULL
     // Post-conditions: None
     std::string getPartNumber() const;

     // Setter Name: setPartNumber
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: A string object
     // Returns: None
     void setPartNumber(std::string);

     // Function Name: getDescription
     // Purpose: To get the description for the part
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     // Pre-conditions: Description cannot be empty
     // Post-conditions: None
     std::string getDescription() const;

     // Setter Name: setDescription
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: A string object
     // Returns: None
     void setDescription(std::string);

     // Function Name: getPrice
     // Purpose: To get the price for the part
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     // Pre-conditions: Node cannot be NULL
     // Post-conditions: None
     double getPrice() const;

     // Setter Name: setPrice
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: A double object
     // Returns: None
     void setPrice(double);
};

 class Node
 {
 private:
     // Variable Name: next
     // Purpose: Points to the next node
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node* next;

     // Varible Name: CarPart
     CarPart* carPart;

 public:
     // Default Constructor Name: Node
     // Purpose: Default constructor to initialize
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node();

     // Parameterized Constructor Name: Node
     // Purpose: Parameterized constructor to initialize
     // Parameters: A string value
     // Returns: None
     Node(std::string);

     //Destructor
     //Purpose:Deletes any dynamically allocated storage
     //Parameters: None
     //Returns: None
     ~Node();

     // Getter Name: getNext
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node* getNext();

     // Setter Name: setNext
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: A pointer to next node
     // Returns: None
     void setNext(Node*);
 };

 class List
 {
 private:
     // Variable Name: numNodes
     // Purpose: Variable that contains the number of nodes
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     // Pre-conditions: Must be of type int
     // Post-conditions: None
     int numNodes;

     // Variable Name: next
     // Purpose: Points to the first node
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node* firstNode;

     // Variable Name: next
     // Purpose: Points to the last node
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node* lastNode;

 public:
     // Default Constructor Name: List
     // Purpose: Default constructor to initialize
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     List();

     //Destructor
     //Purpose:Deletes any dynamically allocated storage
     //Parameters: None
     //Returns: None
     ~List();

     // Function Name: push_back
     // Purpose: Take the node and place it at the end of the list
     // Parameters: Node pointer
     // Returns: None
     // Pre-conditions: Node cannot be NULL
     // Post-conditions: None
     void push_back(Node*);

     // Function Name: push_front
     // Purpose: Take the node and place it at the front of the list
     // Parameters: Node pointer
     // Returns: None
     // Pre-conditions: Node cannot be NULL
     // Post-conditions: None
     void push_front(Node*);

     // Function Name: pop_back
     // Purpose: Removes last node from list
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: A pointer to this node
     // Pre-conditions: None
     // Post-conditions: None
     Node* pop_back();

     // Function Name: pop_front
     // Purpose: Removes first node from list
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: A pointer to this node
     // Pre-conditions: None
     // Post-conditions: None
     Node* pop_front();

     // Function Name: getFirstNode
     // Purpose: To get the first node
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: A pointer to the first node
     // Pre-conditions: None
     // Post-conditions: None
     Node* getFirstNode();

     // Function Name: getLastNode
     // Purpose: To get the last node
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: A pointer to the last node
     // Pre-conditions: None
     // Post-conditions: None
     Node* getLastNode();
 };
```

Implementation

```
#include "CarPart Header.h"

//Constructor
//Purpose: Initialize data
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
CarPart::CarPart()
{
    price = 0.00;
    partNumber = "";
    partDescription = "";
}

//Parameterized Constructor
//Purpose: Initialize data
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
CarPart::CarPart(std::string partNum, std::string partDesc, double partPrice)
{
    price = partPrice;
    partNumber = partNum;
    partDescription = partDesc;
}

// Setter Name: setDescription
// Purpose: Initialize data
// Parameters: A string object
// Returns: None
void CarPart::setDescription(std::string)
{
    partDescription;
}

// Setter Name: setPartNumber
// Purpose: Initialize data
// Parameters: A string object
// Returns: None
void CarPart::setPartNumber(std::string)
{
    partNumber;
}

// Setter Name: setPrice
// Purpose: Initialize data
// Parameters: A double object
// Returns: None
void CarPart::setPrice(double)
{
    price;
}

// Getter Name: getPartDescription
// Purpose: Return Data
// Parameters: None
// Returns: partDescription
std::string CarPart::getDescription() const
{
    return partDescription;
}

// Getter Name: getPartNumber
// Purpose: Return data
// Parameters: None
// Returns: partNumber
std::string CarPart::getPartNumber() const
{
    return partNumber;
}

// Getter Name: getPriceNumber
// Purpose: Return data
// Parameters: None 
// Returns: price
double CarPart::getPrice() const
{
    return price;
}

//Node Constructor
//Purpose: Initialize data
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
Node::Node()
{
    next = NULL;
}

//Parameterized Constructor
Node::Node(std::string)
{

}

//Node Destructor
//Purpose:
//Parameters:
//Returns:
Node::~Node()
{
    if (carPart != NULL)
    {
        delete carPart;
    }
}

//List Constructor
//Purpose: Initialize data
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
List::List()
{
    numNodes = NULL;
    firstNode = NULL;
    lastNode = NULL;
}

//Destructor
//Purpose:Deletes any dynamically allocated storage
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
List::~List()
{
    while (firstNode != nullptr&&lastNode != nullptr)
    {
        //1. Create a temporal pointer pointing to your firstnode.  
        Node* tempPtr = firstNode;
        //2. Alter your firstnode to point to the next node;    
        firstNode = firstNode-> getNext();
        //3. Delete the temporal pointer ans set it to nullptr.     
        delete tempPtr;
        tempPtr = nullptr;
        //4. Repeat the process while the list is not empty.    
    }
    firstNode = nullptr;
}

//push_back
//Purpose: Adds the node pointed to by the pointer to the end of the list
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
void List::push_back(Node* newNode)
{
    if (lastNode != NULL)
    {
        newNode->setNext(lastNode);
        lastNode = newNode;
        numNodes++;
    }
}

//push_front 
//Purpose: Adds the node pointed to by the pointer to the front of the list
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
void List::push_front(Node* newNode)
{
    if (firstNode != NULL)
    {
        newNode->setNext(firstNode);
        firstNode = newNode;
        numNodes++;
    }
}

//pop_back
//Purpose: Removes last node from list
//Parameters: None
//Returns: A pointer to this node
Node* List::pop_back()
{
    if (lastNode = NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (lastNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* tempPtr = lastNode;
        lastNode = lastNode->getNext();
        numNodes--;
        return tempPtr;
    }
}

//pop_front
//Purpose: Removes first node from the list
//Parameters: None
//Returns: A pointer to this node
Node* List::pop_front()
{
    if (firstNode = NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (firstNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* tempPtr = firstNode;
        firstNode = firstNode->getNext();
        numNodes--;
        return tempPtr;
    }
}

//getFirstNode
//Purpose: Get the first node
//Parameters: None
//Returns: Returns pointer to the first node in the list
Node* List::getFirstNode()
{
    return firstNode;
}

//getLastNode
//Purpose:Deletes any dynamically allocated storage
//Parameters: None
//Returns: Returns pointer to the las node in the list
Node* List::getLastNode()
{
    return lastNode;
}
```

Driver

```
// add your file prologue information here
#include <iostream>
#include "CarPart Header.h"
using namespace std;

// the printlist function
// Purpose: Prints out the contents for each Node in the List
// Parameter: A list object, by const reference
// Returns: none
void printList(const List&);

// the printFirstNode function
// Purpose: Prints out the contents for the 1st Node in the List
// Parameter: A list object, passed by value to test the copy constructor
// Returns: none
void printFirstNode(List);

int main()
{

    // set up cout for displaying prices
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    // create a List object
    List partsList;

    cout << "\nPart I: multiple node test: push_front and pop_front\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    // build a List using push_front
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("FL2016", "Oil Filter", 18.95)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("RS12YC", "Spark Plug", 4.15)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("D5941", "Digital Tire Guage", 12.15)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("G19216", "Car Wash Solution", 8.15)));

    cout << "\nThe original nodes in the List:\n";
    printList(partsList);
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";

    // test push_front function
    cout << "\nAdding to the front of the List:\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("X-5077a", "Wiper Blades", 15.45)));
    partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("T-280RA", "Turtle Wax Chrome Polish", 3.15)));

    printList(partsList);
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";

    // test pop-front
    cout << "\nRemoving the first node from the list.\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    Node* item = partsList.pop_front();
    printList(partsList);
    if (item != NULL)
        delete item;

    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nPart Two: Push_back and pop_back";

    // test push_back
    partsList.push_back(new Node(new CarPart("C120-X", "Assorted Fuses", 7.25)));
    partsList.push_back(new Node(new CarPart("CTK-120706", "Mechanic Tool set", 126.00)));

    cout << "\nAdding two nodes at the end\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    printList(partsList);

    // test pop-back
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nRemove last node from the list\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------\n";
    item = partsList.pop_back();
    printList(partsList);
    if (item != NULL)
        delete item;



    cout << "\n-------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nEnd of Test";
    cout << "\n-------------------------------------------\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

// you have to fill in the code for this function
void printList(const List& theList)
{
    cout << theList.;
}

// you have to fill in the code for this function
void printFirstNode(List theList)
{
    cout << theList.getFirstNode;
}
```

Comment: Why posting all of that code, instead of only the relevant parts?

Comment: The compiler doesn't just tell you what's wrong, it also tells you *where* it determined that something's wrong. Look there. What does your code say? What do you want the code to do? Also, there are several other errors in your code, such as the syntax error in `cout << theList.;`.

Comment: I am posting code that I have so you guys can tell me, I have no idea where the problem is or I would fix it

Comment: Have you at least try to understand the error by yourself first?!
How can you convert a CarPart into a std::string from your code?
Consider reading this [tutoriel](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

Comment: and hvd I tell you where it says its wrong if you read my description

Comment: @DEnumber50 I did read your description. That's where I saw you included the error your compiler gives. That's where I didn't and don't see *where* in your code that error is, *even though your compiler is already telling you that*.

Comment: Of course I have tried to solve this myself, I wouldn't post it if I didn't

Comment: partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("FL2016", "Oil Filter", 18.95))); from the driver code

Comment: Again at hvd in my description I say there is that syntax error, and I am aware of it for cout << theList.;

Comment: And you defined Node::Node(std::string) which is not CarPart*

Comment: Ah, *that* comment is much clearer. That the error is in `partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("FL2016", "Oil Filter", 18.95)));` was not at all clear from your question. Okay, now look at what the error says. It says it cannot call `Node`'s constructor with a `CarPart *`. That seems like an appropriate error to me: you didn't define any constructor taking a `CarPart *`. What do you want your code to do? Which constructor are you attempting to call?

Comment: I suspect that you didn't see the line number in front of the error message.  The error is occuring in `main`, in the lines where you are pushing new elements onto the list.  Look at those lines, and see if you can spot the error (or read the answer below)...  In case you can't find the line I mean, it is this one: ` partsList.push_front(new Node(new CarPart("FL2016", "Oil Filter", 18.95)));` (and of course the three lines following it.

Comment: By the way, you can make your code a lot shorter by removing redundant information. The comments don’t need to repeat the variable name, since that same name is written below. Also, variables don’t have preconditions or postconditions, only methods can have them. Variables can have invariants. Then the code becomes easier readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere in here....

```
 class Node
 {
 private:
     // Variable Name: next
     // Purpose: Points to the next node
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node* next;

     // Varible Name: CarPart
     CarPart* carPart;

 public:
     // Default Constructor Name: Node
     // Purpose: Default constructor to initialize
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node();

     // Parameterized Constructor Name: Node
     // Purpose: Parameterized constructor to initialize
     // Parameters: A string value
     // Returns: None
     Node(std::string);

     //Destructor
     //Purpose:Deletes any dynamically allocated storage
     //Parameters: None
     //Returns: None
     ~Node();

     // Getter Name: getNext
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: None
     // Returns: None
     Node* getNext();

     // Setter Name: setNext
     // Purpose: Initialize data
     // Parameters: A pointer to next node
     // Returns: None
     void setNext(Node*);
 };
```

do you have the needed constructor for...

```
new Node(new CarPart...
```

The only constructor that takes an argument is...

```
Node(std::string);
```

hence the error you're seeing.